# How to run cs-script (c# script) with StringTemplate?

Tags: c#

I copied Antlr3.StringTemplate.dll and Antlr3.Runtime.dll from http://www.stringtemplate.org/ to cs-script/lib directory ( http://www.csscript.net/ ) and execute the code below but it says it cannot find the assemblies of Antlr why ? My prog below

```
//css_reference Antlr3.Runtime.dll;
//css_reference Antlr3.StringTemplate.dll;

using System;
using Antlr.StringTemplate;
using Antlr.StringTemplate.Language;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Script
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {


StringTemplateGroup group =  new StringTemplateGroup("myGroup", @"C:\Tutorials\stringtemplate", typeof(DefaultTemplateLexer));
StringTemplate helloAgain = group.GetInstanceOf("homepage");

helloAgain.SetAttribute("title", "Welcome To StringTemplate");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("name", "World");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Terence");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Kunle");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Micheal");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Marq");

Console.Out.WriteLine(helloAgain.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it really say this? Or does it say *"...or one of its dependencies..."*? I would recommend using fusion log and see whether any dependencies are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that CS-Script cannot resolve Antlr3.*.dll assemblies.

You need to instruct the script engine where these assemblies may be located and if you do not do this CS-Script will look only in the GAC, your local directory (where the script is) and in the [cs-script]\Lib.

You have a few options to solve the problem:

- You can specify assemblies with the absolute path
- Add probing directories to the CS-Script global settings or directly to your script.
- Register Antrl in GAC.

Have a look at [AddingSearchDirs](http://www.csscript.net/help/Adding_Searchdirs.html) and www.csscript.net/help/Using_.NET_assemblies.html, this will help you to start.

Comment: finally it's due to download package from official page doesn't work, have downloaded from elsewhere it's better.

Comment: STILL HAVE AN OTHER ERROR: C# Script execution engine. Version 2.7.3.0.
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Oleg Shilo.

Error: Specified file could not be compiled.

(0,0): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Antlr3.StringTemplate.dll' could not be found